# AES-GCM decryption error iaik.cms.CMSException: Unable to decrypt encrypted content-encryption key: Invalid padding

Tags: aes-gcm

I am using following code to encrypt data using AES-GCM:

```java
// the stream to which to write the EnvelopedData
ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
EnvelopedDataOutputStream envelopedData;

//  wrap EnvelopedData into a ContentInfo 
ContentInfoOutputStream contentInfoStream = 
  new ContentInfoOutputStream(ObjectID.cms_envelopedData, resultStream);
// create a new EnvelopedData object encrypted with AES
try {
 envelopedData = new EnvelopedDataOutputStream(contentInfoStream,                                                     
 (AlgorithmID)AlgorithmID.aes256_GCM.clone());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
 throw new CMSException("No implementation for AES.");
}

// create the recipient infos
RecipientInfo[] recipients = new RecipientInfo[1];
// user1 is the first receiver
recipients[0] = new KeyTransRecipientInfo(signCert, 
(AlgorithmID)AlgorithmID.rsaEncryption.clone()); 

// specify the recipients of the encrypted message
envelopedData.setRecipientInfos(recipients);
//int blockSize = 2048; // in real world we would use a block size like 2048
//  write in the data to be encrypted
//byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
//byte[] buffer;
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
 envelopedData.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

But while trying to decrypt the same using following code:

```java
EnvelopedDataStream enveloped_data = new EnvelopedDataStream(is);
enveloped_data.setupCipher(privateSignKey, 0);
InputStream decrypted = enveloped_data.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();      
ByteStreams.copy(decrypted, os);
os.close();
```

I am getting following error:

```
iaik.cms.CMSException: Unable to decrypt encrypted content-encryption key: Invalid padding!
```

I am not sure of block size to be used, this might be a reason for the error, but not sure.

Moreover, if I compare my encrypted file with that of a correct one, I see following difference:

My encrypted data:

```
OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.46 aes256-GCM (NIST Algorithm)
   SEQUENCE (1 elem)
     OCTET STRING (12 byte) FE5729470184A04A5AA30158
```

Correct data:

```
OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.46 aes256-GCM (NIST Algorithm)
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  OCTET STRING (12 byte) CA985F7EAFB709DF711DCA2A
  INTEGER 16
```

Could you please help us in getting this to work?

Comment: Hi, now I am getting this error: en/decryption error: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: MAC verification not successful!

Comment: you should set the loop to `while ((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0) {` and not `!= -1` and please add the key length to your question.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks! Changed code as per your suggestion. Unfortunately, same error. Sorry, if I haven't understood your question, but key length should be 256.

Comment: It looks like authentication tag is missing in encrypted data(INTEGER 16). How can we adjust the above code to add this tag?